# Form not posting nor calling controller method

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, angular

I have a simple html form

```
<h1>Create Make</h1>


<form id="form1" method="post" action="api/SampleData/CreateMake"
  enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
 <div>
  <label for="id">Id</label>
 </div>
 <div>
 <input name="id" type="text" />
 </div>
 <div>
  <label for="name">Name</label>
 </div>
 <div>
  <input name="name" type="text" />
 </div>
 <div>
  <label for="abrv">Abrv</label>
  </div>
 <div>
  <input name="abrv" type="text" />
 </div>
 <div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
</form>
```

From my understanding, if the names are correct (which they should be) that information should be automagically converted into an object and on button press it should call the CreateMake method in the controller.

This is the controller method

```
    [ActionName("CreateMake")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CreateMake(VehicleDto vehicle)
    {
        _vehicleService.InsertMake(vehicle);

        return Ok(vehicle);
    }
```

It should take the object and run the insert method, right?
Nothing is being done on button press though, checked console and network on chrome, nothing. Controller method isn't being called either.

Controller does have a route

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SampleDataController : Controller
```

Comment: is there a button that submits the form ?

Comment: first of all, you are using all html tags instead of c# html helpers, use html helpers instead to get result

Comment: @NikolaiKiefer  `<input type="submit" value="Submit" />` is shown right there in the code

Comment: @YashSoni I agree it's better to bind to the incoming viewmodel using HTML helpers but there's nothing actually invalid about a raw HTML form, it won't stop the form being submitted just because you don't use helpers to construct the HTML in the first place.

Comment: do one thing, in action="api/SampleData/CreateMake" , make it action="@Url.Action("Action",Controller)", maybe some problem with url

Comment: Just try "/api/SampleData/CreateMake" url. Looks like you forgot "/" symbol (:

Comment: Timmy have you perhaps got some JavaScript code which is capturing the "submit" event of the form (or the click event of the button) and suppressing the default behaviour? If nothing at all appears to be happening, this sounds like a likely cause. You tagged "angular", is Angular loaded in this page? Perhaps it's doing something you haven't realised.

Comment: I have no JavaScript/TypeScript code binded to it. I've checked the network and console tab, there is quite literally nothing there. No requests are going out, which is weird

Comment: SOLVED: You need to use <form ngNoForm> if you want to use native form submission in angular.

Comment: @TimmyNeutron you should write that as an Answer if it solves your problem. You are allowed to answer your own question (and also to accept that answer), and also others can upvote it if they choose :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED: 
You need to use `<form ngNoForm>` if you want to use native form submission in angular

Answer (score 0):

Your `action` attribute looks suspicious.

```
action="api/SampleData/CreateMake"
```

That would mean the form will post its data to a path named "api/Sampledata/Createmake" underneath the current page's URL.

Try this root relative action:

```
action="/api/SampleData/CreateMake"
```

Comment: Possibly, but OP states that "nothing is happening". If it was posting back _somewhere_ (even somewhere incorrect) they would see a change in the browser window - e.g. a 404 error probably. The only reason this might not happen is if the form submit is being captured by some JS and submission via AJAX is being attempted, but we have no evidence for that, and the OP doesn't seem to have done anything to try and check whether there's any JavaScript involved.

Comment: I've just tried that. Again, no change. Network tab is empty - https://i.imgur.com/tHw1Elw.png same as console. I've stated it in the previous comment, but there is no JS code at all for this.

Comment: I tried going directly to localhost/api/SampleData/CreateMake, but it just returned an error `core.js:1448 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'api/SampleData/CreateMake'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'api/SampleData/CreateMake'`
Not sure if that's related

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a form with a post action maybe incorporate HTML Helpers. You can convert an Action Link to a Button by using bootstrap:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Submit", "CreateMake", "SampleData", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-large" })
```

You could even use a URL Action within a button to specify the correct route

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="location.href=' Url.Action("CreateMake", "SampleData")'" />
```

This should ensure that the controller method is called.

Also, not part of the question but as a recommendation I would suggest using more HTML Helpers in general. It is considered best practise when using MVC and it makes your code much more readable and understandable. For example:

```
using (Html.BeginForm())
  {
    <label for="id">ID:</label>
     Html.TextBox("ID")
     //other componants

   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />    
  }
```

I hope this helps and that you can solve the problem, have a lovely day.